# How to substitute the value of in a column with the one in another column based on several conditions in r?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a long table (data) like the following:

```
Family          Genus           Species                 Genus_new   col2
Pedinellales    Pedinella       uncultured_eukaryote    uncultured  eukaryote
Noctilucales    Noctiluca   Noctiluca_scintillans   Noctiluca   scintillans
Mediophyceae    Chaetoceros Chaetoceros_socialis    Chaetoceros socialis
Noctilucales    Noctiluca   Noctiluca_scintillans   Noctiluca   scintillans
Eustigmatales   uncultured  uncultured_eukaryote    uncultured  eukaryote
Mediophyceae    Chaetoceros Chaetoceros_sp.         Chaetoceros sp.
Gonyaulacales   Heterodinium    uncultured_eukaryote    uncultured  eukaryote
Cryptomonadales Cryptochloris   phytoplankton_environmental phytoplankton   environmental
Prymnesiophyceae    Phaeocystis Haptophyta_environmental    Haptophyta  environmental
Sarcinochrysidales  Pelagodinium   Pelagophyceae_sp.    Pelagophyceae   sp.
Mediophyceae    Skeletonema uncultured_marine   uncultured  marine
Gymnodiniphycidae   Gyrodinium  uncultured_Gyrodinium   uncultured  Gyrodinium
Cryptomonadales Cryptochloris   uncultured_Cryptophyta  uncultured  Cryptophyta
Pedinellales    Pedinellales    uncultured_eukaryote    uncultured  eukaryote
Prasinophytae   Prasinophytae   Pycnococcus_sp. Pycnococcus sp.
```

I want to substitute what is present in the column "Genus_new" with what is present, on the same row, in column "Genus", only when in the column "Genus_new" certain conditions are respected. For example, when in Genus_new the string starts with "unc" or "phyto" or it ends with "phyceae", I want to substitute the string in Genus_new with the one in Genus on the same row.

I tried single for loop like the followings:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  (data$Genus_new[i][startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "unc")]<-data$Genus[i])
} 
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  (prova$Genus_new[i][endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyceae")]<-data$Genus[i])
}
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  (data$Genus_new[i][startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phytoplank")]<-data$Genus[i])
}
```

and it worked.
As I am learning, I would like to put everything on the same code. So I tried two things:

```
#first try
data$Genus_new[startsWith(data$Genus_new, "unc") | 
                  startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "Unc") | 
                  endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyta") |
                  endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyceae") |
                  startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phytoplank") |
                  endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyte")
                ] <- data$Genus
#but, looking at the results, it seems that there is a mismatch between rows (like at rows 2 of Genus_new, I have the value of Genus of row 5 and not of row 2) 

#second try: 
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(data$Genus_new[i][startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "unc")]) {
    data$Genus_new[i]<-data$Genus[i]} 
   else if(data$Genus_new[i][endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyta")]){
     data$Genus_new[i]<-data$Genus[i]} 
    else if(data$Genus_new[i][endsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "phyceae")]) {
      data$Genus_new[i]<-data$Genus[i]}
}


#But I get the following error:
#Error in if (data$Genus_new[i][startsWith(data$Genus_new[i], "unc")]) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> For example, when in Genus_new the string starts with "unc" or "phyto" or it ends with "phyceae", I want to substitute the string in Genus_new with the one in Genus on the same row.

I think we can do

**Approach**

```r
df$Genus_new = ifelse(grepl("^unc|^phyto|phyceae$", df$Genus_new), df$Genus, df$Genus_new)
```

*Note that I have named your data `df`.*

**Result**

```r
> df
               Family         Genus                     Species     Genus_new          col2
1        Pedinellales     Pedinella        uncultured eukaryote     Pedinella     eukaryote
2        Noctilucales     Noctiluca       Noctiluca scintillans     Noctiluca   scintillans
3        Mediophyceae   Chaetoceros        Chaetoceros socialis   Chaetoceros      socialis
4        Noctilucales     Noctiluca       Noctiluca scintillans     Noctiluca   scintillans
5       Eustigmatales    uncultured        uncultured eukaryote    uncultured     eukaryote
6        Mediophyceae   Chaetoceros             Chaetoceros sp.   Chaetoceros           sp.
7       Gonyaulacales  Heterodinium        uncultured eukaryote  Heterodinium     eukaryote
8     Cryptomonadales Cryptochloris phytoplankton environmental Cryptochloris environmental
9    Prymnesiophyceae   Phaeocystis    Haptophyta environmental    Haptophyta environmental
10 Sarcinochrysidales  Pelagodinium           Pelagophyceae sp.  Pelagodinium           sp.
11       Mediophyceae   Skeletonema           uncultured marine   Skeletonema        marine
12  Gymnodiniphycidae    Gyrodinium       uncultured Gyrodinium    Gyrodinium    Gyrodinium
13    Cryptomonadales Cryptochloris      uncultured Cryptophyta Cryptochloris   Cryptophyta
14       Pedinellales  Pedinellales        uncultured eukaryote  Pedinellales     eukaryote
15      Prasinophytae Prasinophytae             Pycnococcus sp.   Pycnococcus           sp.
```

---

**Data**

```r
df = 
  structure(list(Family = c("Pedinellales", "Noctilucales", "Mediophyceae", 
                            "Noctilucales", "Eustigmatales", "Mediophyceae", "Gonyaulacales", 
                            "Cryptomonadales", "Prymnesiophyceae", "Sarcinochrysidales", 
                            "Mediophyceae", "Gymnodiniphycidae", "Cryptomonadales", "Pedinellales", 
                            "Prasinophytae"), 
                 Genus = c("Pedinella", "Noctiluca", "Chaetoceros", "Noctiluca", "uncultured",
                           "Chaetoceros", "Heterodinium", "Cryptochloris", "Phaeocystis",
                           "Pelagodinium", "Skeletonema", "Gyrodinium", "Cryptochloris", 
                                                        "Pedinellales", "Prasinophytae"), 
                 Species = c("uncultured eukaryote", "Noctiluca scintillans", 
                             "Chaetoceros socialis", "Noctiluca scintillans", 
                             "uncultured eukaryote", "Chaetoceros sp.", "uncultured eukaryote", 
                             "phytoplankton environmental", "Haptophyta environmental", "Pelagophyceae sp.", 
                             "uncultured marine", "uncultured Gyrodinium", "uncultured Cryptophyta", 
                             "uncultured eukaryote", "Pycnococcus sp."), 
                 Genus_new = c("uncultured", "Noctiluca", "Chaetoceros", "Noctiluca", "uncultured", "Chaetoceros",                  
                               "uncultured", "phytoplankton", "Haptophyta", "Pelagophyceae", 
                               "uncultured", "uncultured", "uncultured", "uncultured", "Pycnococcus"), 
                 col2 = c("eukaryote", "scintillans", "socialis", "scintillans", 
                          "eukaryote", "sp.", "eukaryote", "environmental", "environmental", "sp.", "marine", 
                          "Gyrodinium", "Cryptophyta", "eukaryote", "sp.")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```